# How can I integrate secure messaging react native chat project?

Tags: mysql, react-native, security, chat, end-to-end

I am developing a chat app application using React native. As a database, I also want to include mysql in my secure messaging project. For this, end-to-end encryption is required. Can you give me an idea of how to do it?

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like: https://www.npmjs.com/package/hybrid-crypto-js for your encryption and decryption. And in order to achieve real time chatting you can use https://socket.io/ You shouldn't store private keys in your database, these should be kept secret on each device, say in AsyncStorage in case of react native. Messages should be stored on the device (like whatsapp) or encrypted in your database.

My advice is try each package on its own then integrate them together, you can start by implementing a basic chat using socket.io then try to encrypt and decrypt the messages. Follow this article for details: https://dev.to/kris/buiding-chat-app-with-react-native-and-socket-io-4p8l